# C++ Deep Copy Vector Pointer Object

Tags: c++, vector, copy, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a class called Heap that is a Vector of pointers to HeapItem objects

```
vector<HeapItem*> myHeap;
```

I want to create a deep copy of Heap so that I can delete all the items in the copy without affecting the original Heap.

EX:

```
OriginalHeap = new Heap();
OriginalHeap.Insert(HeapItem1);
OriginalHeap.Insert(HeapItem2);
OriginalHeap.Insert(HeapItem3);

CopyHeap = OriginalHeap;
CopyHeap.deleteMin();

print(OriginalHeap);
print(CopyHeap);
```

Output:

OriginalHeap = HeapItem1,HeapItem2,HeapItem3

CopyHeap = HeapItem2, HeapItem3

Comment: is HeapItem a base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you introduce the notion of Heap class which is a wrapper for `vector<HeapItem*>` you can define copy constructor for this class that takes care of desired deep copying:

```
class Heap{
    vector<HeapItem*> data;
public:
    ...  // various constructors if needed
    Heap(const Heap& h) {
        data = new vector<HeapItem*>(h.size());
        for (int i=0; i<h.size(); i++)
            data[i] = new HeapItem(*h.data[i]);    // if HeapItem supports copy construction
    }
    ...  // various member functions if needed
}
```

One possible modification as was pointed out by Chris is to use `HeapItem`'s `clone()` method if former is a polymorphic class - see comments to this answer.

In addition, you might define copy assignment (if you want to be able to assigned one existing `Heap` to another one) and you sure want to define destructor to make sure memory is properly released when the `Heap` object's life is over.

You can also define `Heap` as a template class so that you'd be able to parameterize it with the type of `HeapItem`.

Comment: Have to be a little careful of this approach if HeapItem is a polymorphic type otherwise you could slice the items. The classic solution is to have a virtual clone method on HeapItem. If HeapItem is not polymorphic there is little reason not to store it in the vector by value.

Comment: So you mean instead of `data[i] = new HeapItem(*h.data[i]);` it would be something like `data[i] = h.data[i]->clone();` where `clone()` returns pointer to the `HeapItem`'s subclass?

Comment: Yes, see [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mmjVIC6WolgC&lpg=PP1&dq=coding%20standards%20c%2B%2B%20clone&pg=PT336#v=onepage&q&f=false), for example.

Comment: That page is closed for viewing :( But thanks anyway for the tip, Chris - and +1! :)